# webpack - remove asset from generated html

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Is it possible to remove an asset entry, i.e. `sprite-library.js` from the html file that webpack generates?

A Plugin I am using temporarily creates an entrypoint to a svg sprite sheet which is later removed, but the removal does not remove the following html from the `index.html` which webpack generates.

```html
<script src="sprite-library.js"></script> <!-- this is the line of html I want to get rid of -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index.html` file is likely generated using html-webpack-plugin.
It is possible to exclude chunks in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` as follows:

```js
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    excludeChunks: [ 'dev-helper' ]
  })
]
```

Reference: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks